# Python bindings for libtorrent-rasterbar are not working on debian

Tags: debian, python, libraries

I'm running Debian 6.0.6

I've downloaded  latest version of libtorrent-rasterbar from here: http://code.google.com/p/libtorrent/downloads/detail?name=libtorrent-rasterbar-0.16.6.tar.gz&can=2 and installed it:

```
./configure --enable-python-binding
make
make install
cd bindings/python
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

now I want to test whether the library works:

```
>>> import libtorrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The packaged version of libtorrent from the distributive's repository had some funny behaviour (complaining on boost dependences), so I've decided to upgrade. The same situation is on both of my debian boxes, yet ubuntu box is fine.

Comment: try using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/` in shell